# Questions about "farigxi"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference, affixes

I do not understand this verb. It's parts, *far* and *igx*, would make me think that it means "get made" as in

> The cookies were made in 20 minutes / La kuketoj farigxis dum 20 minutoj

However, I have seen *farigxi* mean "become" as in

> She became a doctor / Sxi farigxis kuracisto

So

> She got made into a doctor?????

This doesn't make sense. Why not just say

> Sxi igxis kuracisto

And farigxi can be reserved for a more literal meaning of "get made"?

PMEG says, on this page https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/subjekto.html#i-gia:

> fariĝi (= “komenci esti”): La domo fariĝis alta. Mia frato fariĝos doktoro. Fariĝis tre varme en la ĉambro.
> iĝi (= “komenci esti”): La mistero iĝas pli kaj pli stranga.

So *igxi* and *farigxi* have the exact same meaning of "komenci esti"? What is going on here?

Comment: As CodeWeawer points out both _fariĝi_ and _iĝi_ mean "to become". My (limited) experience is that _fariĝi_ is more common in speech and standalone _iĝi_ is more frequent in articles etc. thought-out writings.

Comment: Oh, ok, cool! Thanks for explaining! So does that mean that both "ŝi iĝis kuracisto" and "ŝi fariĝis kuracisto" are correct, it's just that "ŝi fariĝis" is more common in spoken language?

Comment: Yes, both are correct and mean the same thing, but _fariĝi_ clearly beats _iĝi_ when it comes to frequency.

Comment: That is so interesting! Thanks for explaining! Do you understand why this is/how it started?

Comment: Why _fariĝi_ is more common? No, I do not know, I can only guess. Quite likely the idea of using suffixes by themselves was so radical or strange idea to the early Esperantists, that they opted for _fariĝi_. At least to me the longer _fariĝi_ sits better in the flow of speech, while _iĝi_ causes a break.

Comment: I just realised another thing. _Dum_ means during a period, but does not mean that the activity took the whole period. Say, it took five minutes to make the dough, then you waited for ten minutes and baking took the last five. Since you were not active the whole time, I think _en 20 minutoj_ is a better expression. See [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/en.html#i-sb8).

Comment: Re-farigxi: interesting! Cool! I didn't realize that! Dankon :-)

Comment: Re-dum: interesting! Cool! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [suffix *-iĝ·*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html) has slightly different meanings, depending on the type of the word to which it's being appended. [Using it instead of a passive phrasing](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html#i-4pm) (*Maria naskis Jesuon en Betlehemo.* → *Jesuo naskiĝis en Betlehemo.*) is only one of its purposes.

### Some uses of the suffix *-iĝ·*

*-iĝ·* appended to a property-word (usually an adjective) produces a verb that indicates that the subject receives that property:

- *pala* (pale) → *paliĝi* (turn pale)

*-iĝ·* appended to an **intransitive** verb (a verb **without** direct object) means that the subject begins the corresponding action, or that the subject performs the action involuntarily.

- *sidi* (sit, = be in a seated position) → *sidiĝi* (sit, sit down = become seated, get into a seated position)
- *morti* (die) → *mortiĝi* (lose one's life)

*-iĝ·* appended to a **transitive** verb (a verb **with** a direct object) means that the subject does this action to itself or by itself, or that we don't care about the actual actor.

- *La knabo **turnis** sian kapon.* (The boy turned his head.) — *La tero turniĝas ĉirkaŭ sia akso.* (Earth turns around its axis. There's nothing/nobody turning the Earth, it turns by itself.)

### fariĝi

*fari* is a **transitive** verb. (It usually has a direct object):

- Mi faras kukojn. — I make **cakes**.
- Oni faris lin generalo. (They made **him** a general.)

The sentence

> La kuketoj fariĝis dum 20 minutoj.

would thus mean that the cookies somehow made *themselves* (or at least that it was *as if* they did so, i.e. they were very easy, quick and non-laborious to make, so that it didn't really matter who did that little work.)

> Ŝi fariĝis kuracisto.

means that she **made herself become** a doctor. (Not that she forced herself, but that she worked towards becoming a doctor and succeeded. Think maybe of the [term "self-made man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-made_man).) In practice, it's used pretty much synonymous with just *iĝi* (become) (see [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/farighi_ighi.html)).

Comment: But what if we just don't care about who made the cookies? Why does it make it seem like there was no work involved? With giving birth, there is clearly work involved, we are just choosing not to mention the person giving birth. Why are the cookies and *farigxi* different? We are just choosing not to mention who made them. In that PMEG article, it says "ke IĜ-verbo montras, ke la ago okazas pli-malpli per si mem, aŭ ke oni ne interesiĝas pri eventuala kaŭzanto de la ago". It say "***aux***", so doesn't that mean it could be either?

Comment: I do see that you say "The suffix -iĝ· has slightly different meanings, **depending the word to which it's being appended**". So does this just mean that it is random? And you just need to memorize the specific meaning of a certain transitive verb when *-igx-* is added onto it? Isn't this kind of memorization supposed to be avoided in Esperanto?

Comment: I meant that the meaning of "-iĝ·" depends on the **type** of the word/root (adjective, transitive verb, intransitive verb, noun, ...) to which that suffix is appended. I've edited the answer accordingly. For this aspect, memorizing that suffix's meaning for the categories on [that PMEG section](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html) should be sufficient.

Comment: **But** there might be special established meanings of compound words that you can't completely derive from Esperanto's word building system. "Malsanulejo" e.g. is not just _any arbitrary_ place or facility for not-healthy persons, it's quite specifically a _hospital_. It seems to me like "fariĝi" has such an established meaning, which is probably why it has got (together with "iĝi") it's [own section](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/farighi_ighi.html) in PMEG.

Comment: Such established meanings of compound words have also to be remembered. They usually don't contradict the meaning derivable from how the word is built, but are usually more specific / somewhat narrower. Whether "fariĝi" can or cannot be used, when we just want to express that we don't care who made something (e.g. the cookies), I'm not sure. "Naskiĝi" is special (and I'd say, one of the established specific meanings) because the perspective of someone getting born (without caring about who gives birth) is such a commonly taken one.

Comment: The usual way to express cooking having been made without caring who did it would be normal passive voice, i.e. "esti" + passive participle. ("La kuketoj estas farita dum 20 minutoj." or "La kuketoj estis farata dum 20 minutoj." — The second option probably better indicates that 20 minutes is how long it took to make them.)

Comment: As usual the oni-passive is simpler: _Oni faris la kuketojn en 20 minutoj._ Or if you want to emphasise the cookies: _La kuketojn oni faris en 20 minutoj_.

Comment: OK, I think I mostly get it now! Thanks so much! :-) Dankegon!

Answer (score 2):

Consider how broad the verb "to make" can be in English, just as in Esperanto:

> They made her a star.

> He made it rain.

> I made it more pleasant.

These examples are practically just causative: *"They [caused] her [to become] a star"*, for example.

Meanwhile, *-iĝ-* is an intransitivizer, which in this case essentially leaves us with this sense "to become". That having been said, "She became a doctor" doesn't strictly go hand-in-hand with "She was made a doctor", because *-iĝ-* doesn't necessarily say anything about whether an action was *done to* someone/something, [as PMEG points out](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/farighi_ighi.html):

> la sufikso IĜ, [kiu] montras ŝanĝon de stato **sen ekstera kaŭzanto**.

… but in the case of *far/i* it doesn't matter, because its meaning is as broad as the English verb "to do". If you prefer, you can think of "fariĝi" like "do become", "did become", etc. "She did become a doctor".

Comment: Interesting! Cool! Can I also use "farigxi" in the cookie context? "La kuketoj farigxis"? And with the doctor, could I also say "Sxi igxis kuracisto" as well as "Sxi farigxis kuracisto"?

Comment: "La kuketoj fariĝis kio?", sed ili estis kaj estas kuketoj. Eble: "ili (fin)kuiriĝis post 20 minutoj" aŭ "ili pretis post 20 minutoj".

Comment: La kuketoj ne fariĝis io ajn. Ili nur *fariĝis*. The reason I am confused is because with any other verb, you could use it exactly like that: Mi fandis la glacion / La glacio fandiĝis. The ice didn't melt *into* anything, it just melted. Same with the cookies, they didn't get made *into* anything. They just got made. I also like your ideas of *kuiriĝi* and *preti*, but I don't see how this doesn't word with *fariĝi*. Isn't this how *-iĝ-* works with intransitive verbs?

Comment: Also, with those examples of "They made her a star", "He made it rain", and "I made it more pleasant", wouldn't it be better to use "ig"? "Ili igis ŝin stelulo", "Li pluvigis", and "Mi pliagrabligis ĝin" instead of "Ili faris ŝin stelulo", "li faris pluvi" and "Mi faris ĝin pli agrabla"?

Comment: Or are "ig" and "fari" equal in this context?